# How to use Google Cloud Messaging on a local network

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to use the gcm push notification service on a local network.

For example:

I have a mobile App using PhoneGap with the Phonegap GCM Plugin [Phonegap GCM Plugin](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova) and a **local** Jetty Webservice.

The standard use of GCM is:

register device on internet GCM -> get register id for device back to device -> send registerid to the own webservice -> webservice send message with register id (deviceid) to gcm internet -> gcm send message to device 
right?!!

in my case i need a full local use:

I will register the device on **local** GCM -> get register id back to the device -> send registerid to the ownl **local** webservice -> local webservice send message with registerid to the **local** gcm -> **local** gcm send message to device

Is there a way to integrate the "gcm" on my local webservice?